# How to update scripts section in Yeoman generated Grunt hosted application?

Tags: gruntjs, npm, yeoman

I've just set up a Yeoman application, namely Angular.js generator based. I've added new JavaScript file to my scripts directory. In index.html there's automatically generated section:

```
<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Full source code you can reach [here](https://github.com/landeeyo/CodeProject/tree/master/Angular/BuildingReadableAppsWithDirectives).

Why Grunt/Yeoman doesn't detect changes and how can I make an update manually?

Answer (score 0):

The scripts that are automatically added into your `index.html` file are the ones that are declared in the `.bower.json` file (your libraries dependencies such as angular and bootstrap).

Those scripts are automatically added when you run grunt by [grunt-wiredep](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep), which will read the `.bower.json` file and inject your dependencies as script tags inside the `<!-- bower:js -->...<!-- endbower -->` part of your `index.html` file.

**You need to add manually your scripts**.

Comment: Are you sure? Have you seen this file https://github.com/landeeyo/CodeProject/blob/master/Angular/BuildingReadableAppsWithDirectives/.yo-rc.json? There's line `"app-files": "app/scripts/**/*.js",` and it suggests it can scan scripts directory.